# C# ASP.NET, setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal inside an async call stack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I know that when using async/await if we leave the ASP.NET synchronization context and come back to it, ASP.NET sets `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User`. But what happens as we go up an async call chain? I believe the various contexts flow one way. Except `HTTPContext` which is static for a user.

1. What happens with the next continuation up the call chain?

   1. Will the next continuation up the call stack use the captured `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and context from when it was awaited?
   2. Or would ASP.NET also set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User` on each continuation?
   3. Or would the continuations up the stack end up with the default principal?
2. If I was to manually set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, would that be seen up the call stack?

   1. If the continuations were on the same thread?
   2. If the continuation was on another ASP.NET `ThreadPool` thread?
   3. Would I have to set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in each continuation if I wanted to manually set it?

I am working on an existing ASP.NET project with .Net 4.6.1.  Down the call stack a 3rd party component leaves the ASP.NET context. I need the value from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` when it returns from the 3rd party and set `HttpContext.Current.User` to it so it will be reset by the ASP.NET context on the return. At the start of the async chain I restore `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and HttpContext.Current.User. But I want to move this further down the stack. I am not using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: You can see how to format here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Note that you're asking a number of questions here. They are all related and intertwined, so I don't think the question is overly broad, but there are some who might feel that way.

Comment: By the time I edited the format, you had already finished it lol. I'm asking about all the possible scenarios since I have only found partial info on this topic. Answers typically don't go beyond "ASP.NET sets Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User when returning to the AspNetSynchronizationContext" if the answers even get that far. And I need more info...

Comment: How is that 3rd party component leaving the ASP.NET context and returning to it? What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: I don't know exactly how it is, I just know that it is based on Thread.CurrentPrincipal == HttpContext.Current.User after the call to it, but they are different before the call. And knowing AspNetSynchronizationContext does that when returning to it. The 3rd party component is RestSharp which is wrapped in code generated from YAML from our client to connect to their APIs.

Comment: I can do async calls and asp.net seems to act as it normally does. But as soon as it leaves the asp.net context, it changes. Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User seems to be set on each async/await continuation. Even worse, it appears to do it past where the async chain started in the button click event. I can see this even in the PreRender event of a composit control on the page and the page PreRender event itself. I can change HttpContext.Current.User and subsequent methods end up with Thread.CurrentPrincipal being set to it. I am testing in VS with debug mode though...